# Django to give limitation for postjob

Tags: django

Am having tables in database like EmployerRegistration and PostJob. Am relating those tables with empid(foreign key of PostJob). Using this empid I need to PostJob at maximum of 5.I want to display alert message like number of post available while login. Some one help how to give views for this condition.

```
models.py
class EmployerRegistration(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class PostJob(models.Model):
    emp = models.ForeignKey(EmployerRegistration)
    jobtitle = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    jobsummary = models.TextField()
    key_skills = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    experince = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    salary = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Are you talking about javascript alert? If not javascript alert, then I suggest you to look at this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

views.py

```
def your_view(request, empid):
    msg=""

    if request.method == "POST":
        jobs = PostJob.objects.filter(emp_id=empid).count()
        if jobs <= 5:
            //save
        else:
            msg = Your not allow to add new post job. 

    return render(request, 'page.html', {'msg': msg})
```

template

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var msg = {{msg}}
        if(msg != ""){
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
</script>
```